# Trouble installing php-cli

Tags: software-installation, php

I am trying to install php5-cli package on my machine but I get the following error for unmet dependencies.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmaven2-core-java : Depends: libdoxia-core-java (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 php5-cli : Depends: libonig2 (>= 5.9.5) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libqdbm14 (>= 1.8.74) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: php5-json but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: php5-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried apt-get install -f, apt-get clean and apt-get autoclean none of which helped. I have tried almost all the solutions given in this post [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) but none of them seemed to work for me.

edit:I tried installing the packages individually using

```
sudo apt-get install php5-readline php5-json php5-common libqdbm14 libonigia-core-java libmaven2-core-java 2 libdox
```

but that didn't seem to work either.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libonig2 is already the newest version.
libmaven2-core-java is already the newest version.
libmaven2-core-java set to manually installed.
libqdbm14 is already the newest version.
php5-common is already the newest version.
php5-json is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-readline : Depends: php5-cli (= 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Here is the output for apt-cache policy php5-readline

```
php5-readline:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
  Version table:
     5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     5.6.12+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2 0
        500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 0
        500 http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

the output to  `grep -r 'ftp.us.debian.org' /etc/apt/ and apt-cache policy libmaven2-core-java` is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.save:deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.bak:deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
grep: and: No such file or directory
grep: apt-cache: No such file or directory
grep: policy: No such file or directory
grep: libmaven2-core-java: No such file or directory
```

And this is the output to the script:

```
alsa-base http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
cgroupfs-mount http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
curl http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
dmsetup http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
dnsmasq-base http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libarchive13 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3-gnutls http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libdevmapper1.02.1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libeclipse-aether-java http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libgnutls-deb0-28 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libgnutls-deb0-28 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libgnutls-openssl27 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libgrpc-dev http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libgrpc0 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libhogweed4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libhogweed4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libjsch-java http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libnettle6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libnettle6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
librtmp1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
librtmp1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libsisu-inject-java http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libssh2-1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libssl-dev http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libssl1.0.0 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libssl1.0.0 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libtasn1-6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libtasn1-6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libunwind8 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libwagon-java http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
libwagon2-java http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
pepperflashplugin-nonfree http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/contrib amd64 Packages
```

output for `apt-cache policy libmaven2-core-java`

```
libmaven2-core-java:
  Installed: 2.2.1-22
  Candidate: 2.2.1-22
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.1-22 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.1-17 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
```

I followed the steps in the answer, removed the repository, ran apt-get -f install and had to do an autoremove to remove some packages that were not required anymore. It seemed to have resolved the issue with libmaven2-core-java. I then tried to install php5-cli again but I got the following output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2) but 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 is to be installed
            Recommends: php5-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

output to sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 53 not upgraded
```

and output to sudo apt-get install php5-cli

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-cli : Depends: php5-common (= 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2) but 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 is to be installed
            Recommends: php5-readline but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

the output for apt-cache policy php5-common

```
php5-common:
  Installed: 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
  Candidate: 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
  Version table:
 *** 5.6.12+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

The output to dpkg -l | grep 'sury' is

```
ii  php5-json                                            1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1               amd64        JSON module for php5
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy php5-cli; apt-cache policy libmaven2-core-java; apt-cache policy libdoxia-core-java; apt-cache policy libonig2`

Comment: And where is the output of the command's above? And now I need `apt-cache policy php5-readline` too

Comment: Purge this ... ppa:ondrej PPA!

Comment: I've added an answer in progress, follow my steps exactly and give me a report.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'ftp.us.debian.org' /etc/apt/` and `apt-cache policy libmaven2-core-java`

Comment: And [edit] your question and add the output of [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12313065/) script.

Comment: and means and =) Give me the output of `apt-cache policy libmaven2-core-java`

Comment: oops! Sorry! Must have overlooked it. Edited the question to include it now

Comment: Updated my answer. Don't forget to give me the result. And ping me with @A.B. in your contents. Without that, I don't get a notification.

Comment: @A.B. I just updated my question with the result from the steps. The issue with libmaven2-core-java seemed to have resolved but I still could not install php. Thanks for all your help btw! :)

Comment: The PPA ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 is still active. Purge it as described in my answer and don't forget the `sudo apt-get update `

Comment: @A.B. I tried purging it but I got this "Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: ondrej php5-5.6
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ondrej php5-5.6"

Comment: Start `sudo apt-get update` now.

Comment: @A.B. done! But still getting the same message with the php5-cli installation

Comment: [Edit] your question again and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f;; sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

Comment: @A.B. just updated the question with the outputs you requested

Comment: Thank you again the output of `apt-cache policy php5-common`

Comment: @A.B. added the output to the question

Comment: I have added another downgrade into my answer: `sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2`

Comment: [Edit] your question again and add the output of `dpkg -l | grep 'sury'

Comment: @A.B. That seemed to have done the trick. I did manage to install php5-cli finally! Thank you so much!

Comment: And downgrade this package also: `sudo apt-get install php5-json=1.3.2-2build1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incompatible software repositories enabled. We can fix this…

1. Use the main server for the Ubuntu repositories

   ```
   sudo sed -i.bak 's/http:\/\/pk\./http:\/\//' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `ppa-purge`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   ```

   If an installation isn't possible and `ppa-purge` isn't installed, download the deb package

   ```
   cd ..
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr57_all.deb
   ```

   extract and copy the executable

   ```
   dpkg -x ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr57_all.deb ppa-purge
   sudo cp ppa-purge/usr/sbin/ppa-purge /usr/sbin
   ```
3. Purge the PPA ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. The next error message

   ```
   libmaven2-core-java : Depends: libdoxia-core-java (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
   ```

   You use an additionally Debian repository, `http://ftp.us.debian.org/`. This repository provides `libmaven2-core-java` which depends on `libdoxia-core-java`. But this package isn't available.

   Therefore remove the repository `http://ftp.us.debian.org/` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. After that, run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   and downgrade the packages with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libmaven2-core-java=2.2.1-17
   ```
5. Usually not necessary after purging the PPA `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` with `ppa-purge`, but in your case downgrade also the packages listed by `dpkg -l | grep 'sury'`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2 
   sudo apt-get install php5-json=1.3.2-2build1
   ```
6. Repair your installation

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Comment: I could not install the ppa-purge package because i am getting the unmet dependencies error with it as well.

Comment: Maybe it's already installed? Check with `apt-cache policy ppa-purge`

Comment: It is not installed. I get Installed: (none) at the output

Comment: Ok, I have added a step into my answer. See point  2 and use "If an installation isn't possible, download the deb package …"

Comment: So I did try that. But that doesn't seem to work either. "libmaven2-core-java : Depends: libdoxia-core-java (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed" keeps popping up. I am not sure why though

Comment: I tried sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid][askubuntu.com/help/…](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)! **;-)**